# About Android SecurityException

Tags: android, exception

I have a simple question. As we know, there are many places in the Android code where SecurityException is thrown for reasons. Is that reasonable that we catch the SecurityException and handle it but not let it crash the application?

Comment: Are you having a specific problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you catch every runtime exceptions, your application may not crash but it may not behave correctly as well. It might even crash at other points as well. The correct way is to handle those security failures. If you're handling a third-party API that can throw those security exception and it is not clear when those exceptions are thrown, then you may catch those exceptions. It is still better to understand why such situations occur - such as missing permissions, not having the required signature, etc.